# Display a result in a GUI scilab with a callback

Tags: callback, scilab

I have this code:

```
button1 = uicontrol(p, "string", "1", "units", "normalized",...
         "position", [0 0 1/3 1/6], ...
         "BackgroundColor", [0, 0.8, 0.8], ...
         "relief", "solid", ...
         "userdata", [A], ...
         "callback", "A = evstr(gcbo.userdata(1).string); area = calculate1(A); gcbo.userdata(2).string = string(area)");
```

This is for a button in a GUI which has other two buttons (See the picture). The goal is that after pushing the button the result is displayed instead of the three dots. I have tested the code several times and the part isn't working is the callback. It actually evaluate the values overall works well, but i can't get the resulte in it's site.

I'll be very thankful if someone could help me.

Here's how the window looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be easier to help if you could post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not reproducible questions are usually downvoted or blocked. Secondly putting a multi line Scilab script inside the `callback` string is a bad practice. Define a function of:

```
function changeText()
   A = evstr("gcbo.userdata(1).String");
   area = calculate1(A);
   gcbo.userdata(2).String = string(area);
endfunction
```

and change that piece of code to:

```
button1 = uicontrol(p, "string", "1", "units", "normalized",...
         "position", [0 0 1/3 1/6], ...
         'style', 'pushbutton',
         "BackgroundColor", [0, 0.8, 0.8], ...
         "relief", "solid", ...
         "userdata", [A], ...
         "callback", "changeText", "callback_type", 2);
```

where the `"callback_type", 2` make sure that a Scilab function is ran when ever the push button is activated.

Now imagining that you have a text of:

```
text1 = uicontrol(p, "style", "text", "string", "....")
```

what you need to do is to first make `text1` variable global, and then change the value of the `text1.String` inside the callback function. It should look like this:

```
global text1;

function changeText()
   global text1;
   A = evstr("gcbo.userdata(1).String");
   area = calculate1(A);
   gcbo.userdata(2).String = string(area);
   text1.String = "some data here";
endfunction

button1 = uicontrol(p, "string", "1", "units", "normalized",...
         "position", [0 0 1/3 1/6], ...
         'style', 'pushbutton',
         "BackgroundColor", [0, 0.8, 0.8], ...
         "relief", "solid", ...
         "userdata", [A], ...
         "callback", "changeText", "callback_type", 2);

text1 = uicontrol(p, "style", "text", "string", "....")
```

If you post a MCVE then I can help better. Success.